Cannot find package 'aws-sdk' imported from /var/task/index.mjs
i am getting this error
even after having the correct configuration
using nodejs 18
{
    "errorType": "ReferenceError",
    "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
    "trace": [
        "ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
        "    at file:///var/task/index.mjs:1:13",
        "    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)",
        "    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)",
        "    at async _tryAwaitImport (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1008:16)",
        "    at async _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1057:86)",
        "    at async _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1081:16)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}

let me know what could be the possible reason
i tried changing file configurtaions, and changeing file type but got the same issue

This question is similar to: "errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead" When using Node.js 18.x. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
